# how to vertically align a child item in centre of its parent height

Tags: c#, uwp, grid, uwp-xaml, stackpanel

I have a stack panel which has another stack panel and I would like the second panel to be at the centre of first stack panel.I changed orientation of these panels and vertical alignment nothing works..

Anybody worked on this ? I would like to have your help.

Update:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="White" Visibility="Visible" Orientation="Vertical">

                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ProgressBar Margin="0,15,0,0"
                     IsIndeterminate="True" 
                     IsEnabled="True" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Margin="6,6,6,15" Foreground="Black" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Loading..."/>
                </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Show what you tried?

Comment: I tried setting the orientation of mother stack to veritcal and child stack to centre

Comment: Show us the code and we will figure out.

Comment: Thanks .. please find the code in my updated question

Comment: @Shiva please accept one of the answers if you found them to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `StackPanel`. What stack panel does is that it stacks the items from one side (top, left...) so it's not possible to fully center an item in `StackPanel`. When items are stacked vertically, the `VerticalAlignment` property has no effect on items that are direct children of the panel. The same applies for `HorizontalAlignment` and horizonal stacking.

You should use `Grid` or `Border` to center items (I also removed the `Visibility` values since `Visible` is the default state):

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.RowSpan="4"
      Background="White"
      >
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.Row="0"
                >
        <ProgressBar Margin="0,15,0,0"
                     IsIndeterminate="True" 
                     IsEnabled="True"
                     Foreground="Black"
                     />
        <TextBlock Margin="6,6,6,15"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontSize="21"
                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Loading..."
                   />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... You have to set Orientation to Horizontal of parent StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="White" Visibility="Visible" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ProgressBar Margin="0,15,0,0"
                     IsIndeterminate="True" 
                     IsEnabled="True" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Margin="6,6,6,15" Foreground="Black" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Loading..."/>
                </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```